# Decode `ts` videos on GPUs?

Tags: opencv, video, ffmpeg

I have a Nvidia Geforce GTX 1080Ti that I am using for video processing. I am trying to decode videos on the GPU and am able to decode `Mpeg-4` videos. However the problem is when I try using this for `ts` files. It errors out with a message saying that the format is unsupported. I am using `opencv::cudacodec::VideoReader` for decoding videos.

I have tried a couple of things-

- Spawning an encoding session to encode `ts` to `mp4` and then decode. However this seems like an overkill.
- Decode using the CPU and then upload the frames to GPU for processing. This seems to be the best solution right now. However it still takes almost 4 times the time it takes for `mp4` files on the GPU.
- Use `ffmpeg` to copy the audio/video streams and change the container to `mp4`. This leads to almost twice the number of frames when decoded on the GPU

I am looking for a solution to decode `ts` files on the GPU.

Comment: The container is immaterial - demuxng is always in software. If the codec is supported on the GPU, then it will work on ffmpeg. OpenCV may be more limited.

Comment: Can you please specify why using ffmpeg with -codec copy option leads to twice the number of frames when decoded on the GPU?

Comment: @Harry I tried with `-acodec copy -vcodec copy`

Answer (score -3):

Change the extension of your file to '.mpeg'. '.ts' is essentially a '.mpeg' file. Hope this helps.

Comment: No it isn't. A transport stream and a container file are not the same thing at all